# How can I access calendar in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I make an Windows 8 app.  How can I access to standard Windows 8 calendar? Is this possible? If not, how to make sth like Windows 8 calendar to add events in it? I need to add event to calendar.

Answer (score 2):

There's a live-connect API.
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the UI (versus API access, as Christopher covered). There isn't a standard calendar control provided from Microsoft.

You can create your own or check out third party offerings, including

1. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/summary.aspx?utm_expid=39875251-14&utm_referrer=http://www.telerik.com/developer-productivity-tools/whats-new.aspx) appears to have a date and time picker, but not a
   calendar currently. Their [KendoUI (HTML5)](http://www.kendoui.com/web.aspx) does have a calendar, which theoretically you could use inside an HTML5/JS Windows 8 application (but I've not tried this).
2. [ComponentOne](http://our.componentone.com/2012/08/15/windows-8-xaml-controls-are-here/) does have a calendar control for Windows Store applications
3. [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/technology-previews/windows8/) also has controls you can use in various scenarios (HTML5 / ARM)